# How to change the default data-source in activiti BPM?

Tags: workflow, activiti, business-process-management, workflow-engine

I would like to change the default data-source to oracle. So as per the user guide `another database the db.properties in the WEB-INF/classes of the Activiti Explorer web application should be changed` if i change the db.properties again i need to create .war file, correct ? How to i create the activiti-explorer.war file ? Or Is there any options for change it from explorer ? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the Activiti Explorer well, but you can build your war file from the activity sources.
Its a simple maven project and should be quite easy.

Have a look to the Activiti Documentation here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ACT/Developers+Guide#DevelopersGuide-Buildingthedistribution

BTW: I use Activiti embedded to spring framework using the spring-activiti extension... works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create WAR again you just put your war in server(tomcat or any other server) and start the server then it will generate an application folder parallel to war file in web-apps folder.

Change the db.properties in application folder generated in web-apps and restart the server.
changes in db.properties will reflect in web application.